# How can I access my application from the public IP of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Whenever I tried to access to my deployed application on an EC2 instance of AWS using the public IP, I get the following messages on Chrome: "This site can’t be reached
ec2-54-194-153-202.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com took too long to respond."

then, What changes shall I apply in order to grant access to the application properly ?,
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check in this case is The **Security-Group** inbound rules attached to your Ec2.

If your application is running behind a webserver like Nginx or Apache, check that your security_group is open in inbound for the public range (0.0.0.0/0) on the http port (80).

You can get this info on the Ec2 panel, click on your instance and check the attached security_group, click on it and check the inbound rules.

[Here is a guide for you.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

Notice : If nothing is running on your Ec2 it will never respond, be sure your app is served by a Nginx/Apache/Tomcat daemon.

Hope it helps !